# How do I clean up this partitioning mess?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, gparted

[image: Screenshot of boot disk - Ubuntu 16.04LTS...]

A couple months ago, purchased a new 1TB HDD and tried cloning if off the working main 500GB drive. Eventually was unable to figure out how to do that so just reinstalled Ubuntu from a Live CD.

After up and running, went and messed around setting up the partitions using GParted and the above screen shot is what I have now.

**Edit: Sorry everyone, had a frustrating day yesterday and couldn't make sense of anything. Another read of the Gparted manual today and I actually found stuff so I'm clear on things now. Thanks for your patience.**

Comment: Don't post images of text copy and paste it!

Comment: I am not sure what "mess" you are talking about. Your partitions don't look messy, and sda1 is a swap partition used by Ubuntu.

Comment: What about SDA4? That's the only one I'm worried about, pretty much guessed the swap partition was necessary. I probably created SDA4 myself when I was stumbling around trying to get it set up originally, but don't know if that 'grub' is important to booting or not.

Comment: Your sda1 swap size is unusual. It looks more like it was a 512MB ESP (FAT32) partition used for UEFI boot and you converted it to swap. Then you may have converted to BIOS boot which requires the bios_grub partition. Gparted flags it as it is unformatted, but it must be unformatted. Gparted should not flag it as an error, since it has bios_grub flag.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You installed Ubuntu in legacy/CSM mode in a GPT drive. The "bios_grub" partition is then necessary to boot. Nothing wrong there and if you delete it your Ubuntu won't boot.